# If Galton did not use least squares then how was he drawing his regression slopes?

Tags: regression, least-squares, history

I read the following from a document online [here](http://gauss.stat.su.se/gu/sg/chapter%25203.pdf).

> Galton was full of
> ideas but was no
> mathematician. He
> didn’t even use least
> squares, preferring to
> avoid unpleasant
> computations.

If Galton did not use least squares then how was he drawing his regression slopes?

Comment: Thanks ! Is there documentation on this process?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

The way Galton proceeded to his regression estimate can be found in Stephen Stigler's book, [The History of Statistics](https://amzn.to/3MXt9Ja), as well as a 1997 paper of his, [Regression towards the mean](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/096228029700600202), published in Statistical Methods in Medical Research. The above table is reproduced from that paper.

The table was used by Galton to decompose the variability of the second generation $d$ as $d^2=v^2+r^2c^2$ where $c$ is the variability of the first generation and $v$ the dispersion of the offspring, since

> the position of a second generation individual was the sum of its `reverted' averaged displacement from its parent (say $rz$, where $z$ was the first generation position) and its random deviation from that position (p.110)

and conclude from the stability over generations that $d=c$. The core of Galton's derivation "with a slight assist from the Cambridge mathematician JH Dickson", is to express the data in the curve as a discretised observation of a bivariate Normal and derive the conditional expectation of the height of the adult children on the height of the mid-parent. (Which in itself was an amazing feat for the time.)